# How to make latin extended work?

Tags: html, character-encoding

I've been googling for some but can't realize how to make letters like `č, ć, ž, š, đ` work. I tried adding `<body lang="sr">` because it actually is Serbian (sr=serbian) but doesn't work. I get this `PoÄetna` instead of `Početna`.

I tried adding `<meta charset="ISO-8859-2">` into the head section but still nothing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pick a character encoding that supports the characters you want to use. ISO-8859-2 should do the job, but this isn't the 1990s any more. UTF-8 should be the default choice.
2. Ensure your editor is configured to save in that encoding.
3. Specify that you are using that encoding with document level meta data: `<meta charset="utf-8">`
4. Specify that you are using that encoding in your HTTP response (this takes priority over the document level): `Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: Yep that works. Thanks.
Accepting as solution after 7 mins.